# What is the meaning of the phrase "from the first cuss" in this context?

Tags: meaning

It is from [Crash Course Anatomy & Phisiology](https://youtu.be/QY9NTVh-Awo). It is at around 1 minute and 30 second to 2 minute. Here it goes:

> Because, as unpleasant as a stick in the eye or tack in the foot may be, pain actually is a great example of where everything we have talked about over the last few weeks all come together. As we trace a pain signal through the nervous system, **from the first cuss** to the Hello Kitty band aid.

Dictionaries say that *cuss* is the same as *curse*, but I still cannot understand what it means there.

Comment: When people step on a tack, or cut themselves, or experience some other sharp sudden pain, they often say %@!*!* That expletive [for example, "dammit!" or "shit!" or "oh fuck!"] is **the first cuss**  (the author may also be playing on the phrase "the first kiss").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build on @Tᴚoɯɐuo's comment:

A "cuss" can by anything from a mild "ouch!" to a vulgar profanity.  See the [definition of cuss (noun)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cuss), follow the (b) link to the definition of curse (noun), definition #2.  The word "cuss" was originally a [dialectic pronunciation](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cuss) of the word "curse" that fell into common use.

The speaker was being overly dramatic to create an atmosphere of fun while speaking about a normally dry and boring topic.